# Is there a way to get currency rate on the frontend?

Tags: javascript, currency, bigcommerce

For BigCommerce shops with multiple currencies and a currency switcher enabled, is there a way to get the currency rate on the frontend?

When selecting another currency, it reloads the page with a query string parameter, but I couldn't find in the docs if the rate itself is exposed somewhere.

Comment: The rate is being pulled from the core app/php code that is the foundation of BigCommerce. A currency API endpoint exists, but that gets a bit complicated. Or you can pull exchange rates from xe.com which will be the same as what BC uses.

Comment: @Alyss thanks for a quick reply! Do you have any docs for currency endpoint? The background is that we have an app that only supports default currencies and one of our app users wants the currency conversion from bigcommerce to be applied for the products that come from our system (we're a search app)

Comment: The documentation isn't live yet, but working on getting it on the developer portal. I've responded below with some information that should give you a way forward if you wanted to use it.

Comment: Create a product with a price set to $1, and then just make an Ajax request to that product with the relevant currency ID set (the one whose currency rate you wish to determine) - `example: site.com/product/?setCurrencyId=2` and just parse the price! The difference would be the exchange rate, right? For example, if you load the product in Euros, and the price is 1.5, and the base price was $1, then you can determine that the currency rate is 1.5 Euro to the US Dollar. I could be wrong here, but does this make sense?

Comment: @root this might be possible, but then there are questions of stock display for this product and not showing it in search results \ storefront

Comment: You can just set the product to hidden :-)
http://screencast.com/t/zbck5A7sYz

Comment: @root yep, true! I will think more about this hack, as it need to work quite fast for the end user, but thanks for the idea

Comment: Your only bottleneck is the web request itself, but it was sounding like you needed to interface with a web API anyway. You can store results in a cookie for X minutes at a time until needing to retrieve the currency rate again. good luck! peace

Answer (score 1):

The endpoints are below. They are subject to the product oAuth permissions.

```
OAuth: /stores/{store_hash}/v2/currencies

Basic: /api/v2/currencies
```

Example of a GET response from this endpoint:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "is_default": "False",
    "date_created": "Thu, 11 Sep 2014 17:10:12 +0000",
    "date_modified": "Thu, 08 Jan 2015 15:12:48 +0000",
    "country_iso2": "AU"
    "currency_code": "AUD",
    "currency_exchange_rate": "1.3885600000",
    "auto_update": "False",
    "location": "left",
    "token": "$",
    "decimal_token": ".",
    "thousands_token": ",",
    "decimal_places": 2
}
```

Example of PUT/POSTable fields:

```
{
    "country_iso2": "AU"
    "currency_code": "AUD",
    "currency_exchange_rate": "1.3885600000",
    "auto_update": "False",
    "location": "left",
    "token": "$",
    "decimal_token": ".",
    "thousands_token": ",",
    "decimal_places": 2
}
```

I would recommend not running this API request from the storefront. I would recommend using heroku or another 3rd party server or using your existing app service to make the request and return the values to the storefront so as not to expose API keys.

Comment: Uff, so there's no way to get this from storefront itself, right? And the only way is to use directly from storefront is to get xe.com directly somehow?

Comment: The only way to get it directly to the storefront is to set up an app or server that can make the API request and respond back to it. You can initiate a request to the server to hit the API with AJAX. There's no other way this information can be exposed to the storefront outside of xe.com/their api.

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin - Were you able to find the solution to it? I have a similar problem using big commerce.

Comment: @Mak13 unfortunately no :( We decided to scrape the product page to get the actual converted price

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin : I have another question but not related to this topic. How can we discuss on that? It is related to showing privacy policy contents in the mobile app, as we could not find any api to get these contents. Any help in this? Thanks

Comment: @Mak13 I'm not a bigcommerce dev, so not sure if I would be able to help here